# Two virtual directories on IIS for secured pages

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, security

I am developing application in .net 4.0.In my web application project it have secured folder.
now i want to redirect only authenticated users to secured pages.

i want to do this making two different virtual directories on IIS.(Virtual directory within one more directory)

can i do this? how can i do this? or is there any way to this?

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

If you like to do that manually with your code, the right place is on `global.asax` the `Application_AuthenticateRequest` trigger. Here is an example, and you can change it according to your logic.

```
protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string cTheFile = HttpContext.Current.Request.Path;

    if(!cTheFile.Contains("/securedir/"))
    {
    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.IsSecureConnection)
    {
        HttpApplication app = (HttpApplication)sender;
        string cookieName = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName;
        HttpCookie authCookie = Context.Request.Cookies[cookieName];

        // if this is null, then the user is not logged in
        if (null == authCookie)
        {
  // for the same check you can also use
  //if(HttpContext.Current.User == null || HttpContext.Current.User.Identity == null || !HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)

            string sExtentionOfThisFile = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(cTheFile);

            if (sExtentionOfThisFile.Equals(".aspx", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                Response.Redirect("/", true);
                Response.End();

                // There is no authentication cookie.
                return;
            }
        }
        }
    }
    }
}
```